# trigger default keyword arg in function python

Tags: python, function, default, default-value, keyword-argument

Is it possible to trigger the default keywork argument of a function in some special cases ?
In particular in this example:

```
def funcA(a, data='dataset1'):
    ... # function code
def funcB(a, b, c, data='dataset42'):
    ... # function code

def func_global(a, b, c, data):
   funcA(a, data=data)
   funcB(a, b, c, data=data)

# standard use, funcA and funcB use dataset5
func_global(1,2,3, data='dataset5')

# desired use : funcA and funcB use the dataset from their default kwarg
func_global(1,2,3, data='default') # this obviously wont work as will call the dataset called 'default'

# what I  want to avoid because I have a lot of functions (A,B,C,...), and I don't want to duplicate:

def func_global(a, b, c, data):
   if data == 'default':
       funcA(a)
       funcB(a, b, c)
   else:
       funcA(a, data=data)
       funcB(a, b, c, data=data)
```

Also a constraint: I cannot change the funcA or funcB.
if you have any suggestion how to avoid the duplication, thanks a lot

Comment: Can you add decorators to your functions?

Comment: Best would be without but if you have a solution with decorators I am interested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a decorator:

```
def default_data(func):
    def f(*args, **kwargs):
        if 'data' in kwargs and kwargs['data'] == 'default':
            del kwargs['data']
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return f
```

Now you need to decorate your functions and simplify `func_global`

```
funcA = default_data(funcA)
funcB = default_data(funcB)

def func_global(a, b, c, data):
    funcA(a, data=data)
    funcB(a, b, c, data=data)
```

If you have access to the code of `funcA` and `funcB` then you can simply decorate them with `@default_data`:

```
@default_data
def funcA(a, data='dataset1'):
    ... # function code

@default_data
def funcB(a, b, c, data='dataset42'):
    ... # function code
```